# How to find the mean distance between a point inside a ball and the surface of this ball?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Say I have a sphere of radius $R$, I would like to know the average distance between a point $M$ inside the ball and the sphere of radius $R$.

Because of the spherical symmetry, we can say without loss of generality that my point $M$ inside the ball is defined by the coordinates: $$ (x=r,y=0,z=0) $$, and the points on the sphere are defined by the coordinates: $$(x=R\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta),y=R\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta),z=R\cos(\theta))$$
then the average distance is :

\begin{equation}
d = \frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{ (R \cdot \cos(\phi) \cdot \cos(\theta)-r)^2 + (R \cdot \cos(\phi) \cdot \sin(\theta) )^2 + ( R \cdot \sin(\theta) )^2 } \cdot  \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d = \frac{1}{4 \pi } \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{ R^2 + r^2 - 2 R r \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) } \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi 
\end{equation}

does someone know how to solve this integral?

I computed it numerically (the mean distance between a point inside a ball and the surface) and the result should be: $$ d = \frac{r^2}{3R}+R $$

Thank you

Comment: You’re not choosing the right location of $M$ in order to best take advantage of spherical coordinates.

Comment: You should also think about relevant trigonometry tools.

Comment: Your calculations do not correspond to your title + please don't rely on an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8utE.png), type your formulas + you integrate over $r$ in these formulas, how can the result be a function of $r$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I get rid of the integral over r to of course get a result which depends on r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my point $M$ inside the ball is defined by the coordinates: $$ (x=r,y=0,z=0) $$

It is best to choose point $M$ on the z-axis to best take advantage of spherical symmetry. Hence,

$$M(0, 0, r)$$

> and the points on the sphere are defined by the coordinates: $$(x=R\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta),y=R\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta),z=R\cos(\theta))$$

This is incorrect. The coordinate on the sphere should be

$$x=R\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),y=R\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),z=R\cos(\theta)$$

> $$d = \frac{1}{4 \pi } \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{ R^2 + r^2 - 2 R r \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) } \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi $$

Your integral limits for $\theta$ and $\phi$ are reversed. As said above, if you set point $M$ on z-axis, then you will get the integral as

$$d = \frac{1}{4 \pi } \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{ R^2 + r^2 - 2 R r \cos(\theta) } \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$$

Do substitution, $u=\cos\theta$, then you get,

$$d = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{ R^2 + r^2 - 2 R r u } ~du=\color{red}{\frac{r^2}{3R}+R}$$

Comment: I don't get why my result should be inverted, if my point M is at the center of the ball r = 0 then it is at an equal distance from all points of the sphere and the mean distance is therefore d = R. Your result gives an infinite mean distance for a point M at the center of the ball.

Comment: Sorry, I double check my calculation and I have fixed it. Yes, it is consistent with the answer in your textbook now. @clement3337

Comment: Thank you for your help, in particular for the coordinate choice of the M point to take advantage of the spherical symmetry!

Comment: Great, glad it helps, you are welcome. @clement3337